# How to compare two lists to keep matching substrings and also how to retain the order based on substring?

Tags: python, list

There is a similar question, posted in other thread, but I would like to have a different output
How to compare two lists to keep matching substrings?

And List A doesn't have a consistent pattern

```
A = ['dataFile1999', 'dataFile::2000', 'Resultx2001', 'Filter2002']
B = ['2000', '1999', '1998', '2005', '2002','2005']

C = [x for x in A if any(b in x for b in B)]

print(C)
```

Output:

```
['dataFile::2000', 'dataFile1999','Filter2002']
```

But I would like to have the output in the same order as the substring list B
also, if there is any string missing - it should still keep the string in the list.

```
['dataFile::2000','dataFile1999','1998','2005','Filter2002','2005']
```

Answer (score 2):

A complicated one-liner, just for the fun ;)
No assumption on the pattern.

```
[filter(lambda a : b in a, A).__next__() if any(b in a for a in A) else b for b in B]

['dataFile2000', 'dataFile1999', '1998', '2005', 'dataFile2002', '2005']
```

or without `filter`

```
[[a for a in A if b in a][0] if any(b in a for a in A) else b for b in B]

['dataFile2000', 'dataFile1999', '1998', '2005', 'dataFile2002', '2005']
```

This would be an equivalent expanded code:

```
l=list()
for b in B:
    if any(b in a for a in A):
        for a in A:
            if b in a:
                l.append(a)
    else:
        l.append(b)
        
print(l)
```

and this a more efficient version:

```
l=list()
for b in B:
    this_element = b
    for a in A:
        if b in a:
            this_element = a
            break
    l.append(this_element)

print(l)
```

Comment: Both are working.. can  you please elaborate the equivalent steps...

Answer (score 1):

As your list A has a consistent pattern, these should work well:

```
C = ['dataFile'+b if 'dataFile'+b in A  else b for b in B]
```

Output:

```
>>> C
['dataFile2000', 'dataFile1999', '1998', '2005', 'dataFile2002', '2005']
```

OR

```
C = ['dataFile'+b if b in ''.join(A)  else b for b in B]
```

Output:

```
>>> C
['dataFile2000', 'dataFile1999', '1998', '2005', 'dataFile2002', '2005']
```

**EDIT**

As OP mentioned that list A can be in consistent in its prefix so:

```
C = [i[0] for i in [[a for a in A if b in a] or [b] for b in B]]
```

Output:

```
['dataFile2000', 'dataFile1999', '1998', '2005', 'dataFile2002', '2005']
```

Comment: Sorry, for late edits... List A does not have a consistent pattern... :-(

Comment: @Alice okay I will make the changes

Comment: @Alice please check if my edit works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add another list comprehension that gets all items of B which are not in C and then add the results to the other list

```
    D = [x for x in B if not any(x in c for c in C)]
    result = C.extend(D)
```

Comment: This gives the result as below:

`code`['dataFile1999', 'dataFile2000', '1998', '2005', '2004']`code`

But I want the result to be in same order as of B

`code` ['dataFile2000','dataFile1999','1998','2005','dataFile2002','2005'] `code`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a copy of `C` and replace its values by matching values from `A` elsewise keep the original value from `C`:

```
A = ['dataFile1999', 'dataFile::2000', 'Resultx2001', 'Filter2002']
B = ['2000', '1999', '1998', '2005', '2002', '2005']
C = B[:] # copy of B

for i, y in enumerate(B):
    _value = y  # Use as default if not matching value found!
    for f in A:
        if f.endswith(y):
            C[i] = f
            break
print(C)
```

Out:

```
['dataFile::2000', 'dataFile1999', '1998', '2005', 'Filter2002', '2005']
```